# Displaying a 3D Image in VTK (.mhd, .raw)

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk

I have a simple file that is supposed to display a medical image in the .raw format by reading it's header from a .mhd file using the MetaImageReader.
I'm not quite familiar with VTK so I tried two different code snippets (actually they are examples from the vtk and the kitware website). None of them worked. As I am new to VTK, I'm not sure if this is the right way to display a 3D Image, since my .mhd file tells me, that the image has 3 dimensions:

```
void render1() {
// read input image
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName("header.mhd");
reader->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> viewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
viewer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

// render window
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

viewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
viewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();

renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
}
```

If I change the reader to e.g. a JPEGReader and load a JPEG File, the image will be displayed.
Another Example I've tried is the following:

```
void render2() {
// read input image
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName("header.mhd");
reader->Update();

// Visualize
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
actor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderer->ResetCamera();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage> style = vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage>::New();

renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
}
```

I don't get any error. Only a window with a black background appears. When I click in the window and move the mouse, a square in the middle of the window appears in a gray-scale from black to white, depending on how far I move the mouse.

It seems to me, as if I made a common simple mistake, but since I use example code from the kitware company itself, I'm stuck here.

Comment: Try using vtkImageSlice and vtkImageSliceMapper instead of vtkImageActor: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/ImageSliceMapper